# How to resolve jquery msie error from a 1.8.2 version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and using jquery v 3.2.1 in it. The extension runs on several websites ( like 20) and has no problem whatsoever with respect to jquery. 
But on one such website, which uses jquery v 1.8.2 there is some conflict of jquery. As in, when i turn my extension on, the site fails to show many components. And the error which i get is,

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`.

I have tried the following from one of the answers regarding this topic.

```
 $ = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    console.log("coming inside");
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
})();
```

But this doesnt solve my problem either. I still get the same error. Please tell me how to resolve this error?

Comment: Browser ... "_This property was removed in jQuery 1.9_"

Comment: Correct. But the website works just fine (with jquery 1.8.2) when my extension is off. However, my extension brings in jquery 3.2.1 and everything falls apart, and the mentioned error is thrown.

Comment: Isn't it so, that the extension jQuery overrides the jquery on the site? Use the jQuery.migrate plugin to utilize older features.

Comment: thing is, both (extension as well as website's) the jquery's are getting loaded. Can you please elaborate on how to use the jQuery.migrate?

Comment: Sounds like you're putting jquery into a script element on the page. This is quite rare and usually shouldn't be necessary. Normally your content scripts run in isolated environment so whatever happens on web page doesn't influence them.

Comment: Not through require. I have a jquery file in my entension and i just mention `jquery.js` in the `js` of my content script.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not a solution which actually solves the problem, rather it is a hack to avoid the problem.

So, the problem arose when jquery 3.2.1 (loaded by extension) was clashing with jquery 1.8.x ( loaded by the website). So, I decided not to load jquery for that particular website.

so, in the content script of the website, I would throw the following.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

and, in the background page, from where I'm loading my jquery, I would add the following.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
            "from the extension");
if (request.greeting != "hello")
{

loadjquery() // load jquery 
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
}
});
```